# Scala's compiler lexer

Tags: scala

I'm trying to get a list of tokens (I'm most interested in keywords) and their positions for a given scala source file.

I think there is a lexer utility inside scala compiler, but I can't find it. Can you point me into the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [simple lexer for a Scala-like language](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/parsing/combinator/lexical/StdLexical.html) is provided in a standard library.

A small utility program which tokenizes Scala source using the same lexer as compiler does [lives here](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/compiler/scala/tools/cmd/program/Tokens.scala)

Comment: Can it give me keyword and comment tokens for scala itself?

Comment: @Rogach I've added a link to Scala internal tokenizing program. Look at the source and you'll know how to do it.

Comment: 2018: Link is broken. There is a reason why link-only answers are considered problematic...

Answer (score 2):

[Scalariform](https://github.com/mdr/scalariform) has an accurate Scala lexer you can use:

```
import scalariform.lexer._
val tokens = ScalaLexer.rawTokenise("class A", forgiveErrors = true)
val keywords = tokens.find(_.tokenType.isKeyword)
val comments = tokens.find(_.tokenType.isComment)
```

Answer (score 1):

[Parser Combinators](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/combinator-parsing.html) might help in what you are trying to achieve here, especially if you later on are not only interessted in keyword parsing.

Comment: Parser Combinators are great, but re-creating a full grammar for scala is quite hard. I was hoping for ready-made solution.